# How to combine date and time into a Date object?

Tags: javascript

I have date in this format:

"DD-MM-YYYY" and time in string format like '8', '8.30', '9', '9.30'.(I could have time in number as well)

How can I combine them to get Date format and have something like this:

Wed Jul 07 2021 09:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date()` constructor always works fine with string as [Shyne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68246496/13946770) also told it permits only valid ISO formatted string.
There are 4 ways of creating `Date` objects with `Date()` constructor, and one of those is:
`new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

Considering your specific problem, a function can be written as:

```js
function parseStringToDate(dateStr, timeStr) {

    // create array of DD, MM, YYYY
    let date = dateStr.split("-");

    // convert timeStr to string if is in float value with fixed 2 decimal points
    if (typeof (timeStr) !== 'string') {
        timeStr = timeStr.toFixed(2).toString();
    }
    let time = timeStr.replace(".", ":");    // "." --> ":"

    date.push(time);    // ['07', '07', '2021', '8:30']
    console.log(new Date(date).toString());
}

parseStringToDate('07-07-2021', '8.30');
parseStringToDate('07-07-2021', 8.00);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// You can combine date and time like this
    function myFunction() {
      var d = new Date("2017-01-18");
      d.setHours(9)
      d.setMinutes(30);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use strings:

```
let date="2021-07-04", time="17:54:37";
let combinedDate = new Date(`${date} ${time}`);
```

note that date and time have to be valid date/time strings:
YYY-MM-DD for date
HH:MM:SS for time